# LocalStorage of JSON not working Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON array in Jquery that I am trying to save to localStorage for later use, but for some reason, whenever I try and save it, it comes up with an error that the object is not defined. Here is my current code:

```
localStorage.setItem("Jsonobject", JSON.stringify(json));

        var jsonobject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(Jsonobject));
```

The error specifically states "Jsonobject is not defined" even though I just defined it in the line above. I have tried "Jsonobject" with single and double quotes and they both come up with the same error. I have followed the instructions on this page, https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/, but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: the error message is pretty... direct/clear/precise. `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(Jsonobject))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happens because you do not put "Jsonobject" in quotation marks then the interpreter of JS assumes that you are referring to a variable and since it does not exist the variable, the interpreter tells you that it is not defined

Error:
`localStorage.getItem(Jsonobject)`

Correct:
`localStorage.getItem('Jsonobject')`

or

```
var itemKey = 'Jsonobject';
// Setting value
localStorage.setItem(itemKey, JSON.stringify(json));
// Getting value
var json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(itemKey));
```

Answer (score 0):

In `getItem()` you need to quote your key `'getItem('Jsonobject')'`